# Connecting to an Amazon RDS with Express

Tags: ios, mysql, amazon-web-services, express, react-native

I’m building an app in React Native and I’ve started testing it on my iPhone (instead of in Simulator), so I’m trying to connect to a MySQL database from my phone. I’ve set up an Amazon RDS and connected it to a MySQL client. The RDS is up and running (I’ve run “nc -zv [RDS_ENDPOINT] [RDS_PORT]” and the connection succeeded).

When I ran “nc -zv [RDS_ENDPOINT] [RDS_PORT]”, part of the output was two IP addresses and their corresponding ports -- one for “src” and one for “dst”. In my current code, I use the “src” address simply because that’s what seems to bring my app closest to working. When I try the “dst” address, the connection times out. When I try the RDS endpoint, I get the generic “network request failed”.

The app worked when I was using a local server, but doesn't now that I’m trying to connect to a database remotely.

Here’s the fetch() call:

```js
fetch('http://[SRC_ADDRESS]/newFriend', {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  },
  body: JSON.stringify({
    name: this.state.name,
    about: this.state.about,
  })
})
.then((response) => alert(JSON.stringify(response)))
.done();
```

Here’s the code in the routes/newFriend.js file:

```js
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var mysql = require('mysql');

var connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host: '[RDS_ENDPOINT]',
  port: '[RDS_PORT]',
  user: 'root',
  password: '[PASSWORD]',
  database: '[DATABASE]',
})

module.exports = router;
```

Right now the fetch() call results in
[this alert.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gfOMA.jpg)

Edit: I've changed the security group as Jordi Molina suggested -- the database now accepts all incoming traffic from all sources -- but that unfortunately didn't get things working.

So, how do I correctly direct the fetch() call to newFriend.js?

In general, is there a best way to connect a JavaScript app with a MySQL backend to a remote server?

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. I have to connect to an EC2 (which is then connected to an RDS), instead of to an RDS directly.

To do so, I followed this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Bz-4wTGD2_Q

And then this tutorial: https://hackernoon.com/tutorial-creating-and-managing-a-node-js-server-on-aws-part-1-d67367ac5171

Then I changed the appropriate URLs (in my fetch() calls and Express connection hosts) to my EC2 endpoint. And it worked!

Answer (score 0):

first of all, if I did understood properly, you want to connect to the MySQL database directly from your phone. I would not recommend a mobile app to connect to a database directly from the phone. Think that the code running on the mobile can be de-compiled and access to the database can be gained by remote exploiters. If you are not doing that and I misunderstood your explanation, ignore this part and keep reading :)

On the AWS side of the question, you should check that the security group attached to the RDS MYsql service allows you to connect from your current IP. (see http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/Overview.RDSSecurityGroups.html)

regards

Comment: I might be connecting to the database from my phone, though I'm not sure. How would you recommend I connect to it?

Comment: I would recommend you to implement a REST api in any language you prefer. This REST API should be served and secured properly.

Have a look at https://savvyapps.com/blog/how-to-build-restful-api-mobile-app, it is a very introductional level article, but may shed some light.

regards